# Laravel 5.4 Mailables adding email addresses together

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

Consider this sample of code that takes an array of addresses and sends each of them an email using the mailables feature.

```
//In my controller

$email = new EmailToWinners($sender_name, $letter);
foreach ($recipients as $recipient){
        Mail::to($recipient)->send($email);
}

//In my App\Mail\EmailToWinner

public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.winner-email');
}
```

The emails all get sent fine but when I was testing this I noticed, it's stacking the emails up.

So I get this in the logs.

```
[2017-02-16 15:58:59] local.DEBUG: Message-ID: <250443348fee18f568f4f263153d5101@testing.dev>
Date: Thu, 16 Feb 2017 15:58:59 +0000
Subject: Email To Winner
From: Example Dev <example@me.dev>
To: 1@example.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

[2017-02-16 15:58:59] local.DEBUG: Message-ID: <1b5f39ef0cc17d4d8573019f3d5ec808@testing.dev>
Date: Thu, 16 Feb 2017 15:58:59 +0000
Subject: Email To Winner
From: Example Dev <example@me.dev>
To: 1@example.com, 2@example.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

[2017-02-16 15:58:59] local.DEBUG: Message-ID: <ddf6c62a7f881f9381693435b48ef5a3@testing.dev>
Date: Thu, 16 Feb 2017 15:58:59 +0000
Subject: Email To Winner
From: Example Dev <example@me.dev>
To: 1@example.com, 2@example.com, 3@example.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

If you look at the emails. The first email shows to 
1@example.com

The second shows to
1@example.com, 2@example.com

The third shows 1@example.com, 2@example.com, 3@example.com

So the first person gets 3 emails.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean with `stacking the emails up`?

Comment: Look at the email headers from the log.

Comment: Looking at your code again, it should really be about the problem, that you create the mail object only once and then send the mail to a user, then you add another ´to`, another `to`, and so on, because its always the same object, that's why you need to generate it in the `foreach`, like provided in my comment, then it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass to `to` method a collection of users:

```
Mail::to($recipients)->send(new EmailToWinners());
```

From [Lavavel Mail Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail#sending-mail):

> The to method accepts an email address, a user instance, or a collection of users. If you pass an object or collection of objects, the mailer will automatically use their email and name properties when setting the email recipients, so make sure these attributes are available on your objects

Comment: But I don't wan't to send 1 email to 10 people, I want to send 10 emails.

Comment: @ahackney Yes it should send 10 emails to 10 users. From docs: If you pass an object or collection of objects, the mailer will automatically use their email and name properties when setting the email recipients, so make sure these attributes are available on your objects

Comment: I tested it. It sent 1 email with 3 to fields.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to make a new email object for each recipient like this.

```
foreach ($recipients as $recipient){
        Mail::to('$recipient')->send(new EmailToWinners($sender_name, $letter));
}
```

Comment: Tried this and it does send 1 email to all of them. But I'd like 1 email per address. 1 email = 1 winner

Comment: @ahackney What do you mean with "1 email per adress", or whats the difference to 1 email to all of them? Do you want to provide different content in every mail? for me, this `foreach ($newsletterMailAdresses as $mailAdress) {
            Mail::to($mailAdress)->send(new NewsletterMail($newsletterText, $mailAdress, $sellerID));
        }` sends one mail to each user that signed up for a newsletter

Comment: I will be providing different content to each user. But for now its just the same email. The main issue though is that in my example is sending user 1@example.com 3 emails, 2@example.com 2 emails, 3@example.com 1 email.

Comment: @ahackney with the code I provided it will send only 1 mail to each recipent. How do you plan to provide different content? Does your mail class care about this then?

Comment: So you're right, that will generate 1 email per address but why is doing it the other way causing that to happen, though?